# Is it possible to pass domain user credential to WebBrowser Control?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I just want to know is it possible to pass domain user account credential to WebBrowser Control to view SSRS Report?

Maybe something like this:

```
    public void GetReportUrl(string repUrl)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(repUrl);
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("UserName", "Password");
        webBrowser1.Navigate(request.RequestUri);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want the current network credentials try

```
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

or

```
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

for the windows user credentials.
You cannot "read" the users password, but the above should suffice for "windows authentication" web pages.

Comment: I actually don't want to pass my credential. But someone else's who has the right to view SSRS report. And when i try the above code. It doesn't work. Am i doing something wrong or it is not possible to do this for reasons?